# Un cut features QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, splitting

I was working on a polygon that I split using the Split features tool. I'd like to put it back into one piece, is there a way to do so? 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Start editing and select both features that you  want to merge, and use Merge Selected Features tool:

[image]

If you want to keep attribute of one the feature in the output merged feature, you need to use Take attributes from the selected feature:

[image]